# powershell: extract meta data from a list of websites

Tags: .net, html, powershell, metadata

I have a list of websites in a text file and I wish to collect the meta data of the home page. How can I do this?

For example, the website "" meta data I want to retrieve is

```
meta name="keywords" content="**Chamber of Mines, South Africa, Mining**
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$web = New-Object Net.WebClient
$a = $web.DownloadString("Http://www.bullion.org.za")
$a | Select-String -Pattern '(meta name="keywords".+")' -allmatches |
   select -expa matches | select -expa value
```

this retuns:

```
meta name="keywords" content="Chamber of Mines, South Africa, Mining"
```

Comment: How do you get this as a hashtable.